# mobile programming and security

Tags: android, encryption, mobile-safari, tablet

I have a general question. My boss wants to me program an application(Y) for him for mobile and tablet which 
1- lets users to buy the company magazine
2- and have a full security issue on the sold magazine. nobody can steal it. nobody can hack it
3- the magazine must be read just inside the application(Y)

The problem is that I am completely new in mobile programming. as I am programmer I think I handle the just mobile programming, but for security issues I don't have any clue. does anybody know how is possible to let an document file be read just inside of an application and encrypt in way that nobody can steal and hack it and distribute it?is it called DRM? any idea or clue would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I am doing similar application which sells books, i am just going to share what i did.

**1** : Integrate a secure payment gateway library for purchases, or use google's but i think it takes 30% amount.

**2** : Save magazine in root folder instead of internal or external memory, even if you are going to save in root folder, people with root access can get those file , so what i did was, get what ever data i need from book encrypted it and saved it in sqlite database and delete the book

**3** : Integrate your own reader inside app ,dont write any intents to open that file then only your application will be able to open that file

Comment: what is the pros and cons with your way?

Comment: pros:- The security of payment you no need to worry , it will be taken care by payment library,
There wont be any original copy of magazine so hackers can't get it
cons:
1.it would take time to develop a method to save data of magazine in database and retreive it

Comment: Thank you so much, Good point to cons, how do you think it be wise to save a magazine with 150 pages be saved in SQLite, which I haven't worked it at all and I don't know what benefits it has

Comment: which format the magazine will be in? pdf or epub or doc ?

Comment: you might have to do some good reaserch , look at these questions which will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390742/simple-pdf-text-extraction-on-android  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600808/extract-text-from-pdf-in-code

Comment: for the securit part, have you thought about using DRM?

Comment: sorry i am not familiar with that